# Having error querying data from GridDB and PostgreSQL using JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, griddb

I am trying to query data from a GridDB and PostgreSQL database using JDBC. I have successfully established connections to both databases, but when I try to execute a query that involves joining data from both databases, I get an error. The error message is: 'ERROR: syntax error at or near "JOIN"'. I have verified that the query works fine when executed directly in PostgreSQL, but I am encountering this issue when using JDBC. Here is the relevant code snippet that generates the error

```
String sql = "SELECT g.col1, p.col2 FROM griddb_table g JOIN postgres_table p ON g.col1 = p.col1";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(griddbUrl, griddbUser, griddbPassword);
     PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        // Process the result set
        // ...
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have verified that the query works fine when executed directly in PostgreSQL, but I am encountering this issue when using JDBC. Here is the relevant code snippet that generates the error.I have tried modifying the query to use the PostgreSQL schema name explicitly and i also tried using the PostgreSQL JDBC driver's escape syntax for joining tables but it didn't work. i am waiting for your valueable suggestion and solution.

Comment: Are you really using the long-obsolete 9.1?

Comment: Unless you have something like foreign data wrappers set up between the databases, you should not expect this to work.  And if you do have that set up, you need to describe it.